# Usar botón para una acción en Python tk

Tags: python, tkinter

Necesito saber como usar el botón con alguna acción, esto es un poco de código algo simple usando tk en Python.

```
from tkinter import *
import random
def generador():
    a = (random.randrange(0, 100))
    z.set(a)
    c.after(500, generador)

ventana = Tk()
ventana.geometry("300x300")

t1 = Label(ventana, text = "GENERADOR DE NUMEROS ALEATORIOS")
t1.place(x = 50, y = 10)

t = Label(ventana, text = "Numeros")
t.place(x = 50, y = 70)

z = IntVar()
c = Entry(ventana, textvariable = z)
c.config(bg = "red", font = ("blue", 25))
c.place(x = 100, y = 100, width = 60, height = 50)

ventana.after(500, generador)

boton = Button(ventana, text ="Cambiar numero").place(x = 50, y= 200)

ventana.mainloop()
```

La idea es que cada vez que presione el botón se pueda cambiar el numero aleatorio, esta predefinido que haga hasta 500 números diferentes en `ventana.after(500, generador)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
boton = Button(ventana, text ="Cambiar numero", command = nombre de la funcion).place(x = 50, y= 200)
```

Si quieres que un botón cumpla cierta función, tienes que usar *command*, y este será igual al nombre de la función. Como puedes ver en el código modificado, solo tienes que hacer una función que haga todo el evento que quieres que haga el botón y listo.

Que quede claro que solo se pone el nombre de la función, no se coloca los parentesis como normalmente se hace en Python, osea que si tu funcion se llama `numero_random()` se colocaría de la siguiente forma:

`"command = numero_random"`

Y con eso cuando presiones el botón, se ejecutara el evento de la función. Espero que te haya sido de ayuda compañero.

Comment: ok muchas gracias, pero no se me ocurre alguna funcion para hacer que funcione, trato de hacer uno que otra pero todas me tirar error de sintaxis

Comment: Por lo que veo quieres hacer un generador de numeros aleatorios para eso puedes usar el modulo random, y la funcion random.randint(1, 10) el primer argumento es el numero donde inicia y el segundo donde termina, si quieres hacer que el usuario elija los numeros puedes remplazar el 1 y el 10 por la variable que guarda la informacion de la entrada.